Best approach to define consensus set of features using Stability Selection for prediction
I try to build a machine learning procedure to predict a continuous variable based on a large set of highly correlated features (~7000 features). I am using a stability selection procedure on LASSO regression to find stable set of features ensuring method generalization. Since I want to avoid any kind of overfitting (data leak), my first guess was to use a nested cross-validation with a 5 folds in the outer and inner loop. But I am still not sure how to perform the analysis properly since every loop will result in a different set of features select. Below what I have currently in mind and I have implemented:

Split my data using 5-folds CV (outer loop)
For each fold generated in (1), I produce a 5-folds nested CV (inner loop)
Stability selection is performed in the inner loop, resulting in a stable set of features, testing the model performance in the validation set. For each inner fold I obtain a set of features at least present in X% of my resampling iterations needed for Stability Selection. Performance is evaluated for each inner loop using a linear regression with the corresponding stable features. Other methods such as Random forest or non-linear models could be considered here.
I then fit a linear regression using the union of features from the inner loops, evaluating the RSME on the remaining fold in outer CV
Repeat (3)-(4) for every fold in the outer loop, will result in 5 sets of features and corresponding performance metrics
Final model on the complete dataset is fitted using either the consensus features from each outer fold or using some threshold criterion

My questions are: Is my embedded process to select features legit ? I mean combining both stability selection on LASSO to fit a linear regression with only a limited number of features is correct ? Is the right way to avoid overfitting at the end ?
Your comments and suggestions are welcome
